# Redirect all .php requests to .html using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The following code works to hide .php and replace it with .html

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]*)/([^.]*)\.html/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/%2/index.php [L]
```

I would like to redirect all .php requests to .html.
All .php files are inside a sub directory in "https://www.sitename.com/user/".
For example

```
https://www.sitename.com/user/login/index.php
https://www.sitename.com/user/name/index.php
https://www.sitename.com/user/register/index.php
https://www.sitename.com/user/logout/index.php
https://www.sitename.com/user/dashboard/index.php
https://www.sitename.com/user/contact/index.php
```

It should redirect to

```
https://www.sitename.com/user/login.html
https://www.sitename.com/user/name.html
https://www.sitename.com/user/register.html
https://www.sitename.com/user/logout.html
https://www.sitename.com/user/dashboard.html
https://www.sitename.com/user/contact.html
```

Adding separate line of .htaccess code for each folder will be difficult, can someone help with  simple code to automatically detect and redirect .php to .html ?

Explanation:
If some try to access "`sitename.com/user/login/index.php`", it should load "`sitename.com/user/login.html`".

`sitename.com/user/login.html` should be the only URL that is visible to users. Even if someone try to access "`sitename.com/user/login/index.php`", it should redirect/rewrite to "`sitename.com/user/login.html`".
Enter `sitename.com/user/login.html` in browser = `sitename.com/user/login.html`
Enter `sitename.com/user/login/index.php` in browser = `sitename.com/user/login.html`

Comment: You are confusing "rewrite" and "redirect" :-) If you want to hide something, you want to rewrite. The `?` at the end of your regex should be optional I gues?

Comment: @Daniel W, what I want is to redirect requests going to original script location to fake URL (here php to html).

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "redirect"? What have you tried to make that work?

Comment: @NaveenMp that's not redirect. That's rewrite.

Comment: Does the same file exist with `.html` extension?

Comment: @Nico Haase, the original script url is "sitename.com/user/login/index.php", with the help of .htaccess rewrite "sitename.com/user/login.html" also works. But still the "sitename.com/user/login/index.php" is accessible. I dont want the .php file to load in any way. only the short .html url should be visible.

Comment: @Amit Verma, no the .html url is working using .htaccess rewrite.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it - if you don't want that `index.php` loads in any way, you don't need any redirect - if you want it to redirect to any other URL, why not add redirect rules? Please explain what **exactly** should happen if anybody requests `sitename.com/user/login/index.php`

Comment: @Nico Haase, "sitename.com/user/login/index.php" is the original existing file, I dont want browsers to show the exact path. Always show the fake path with .html extension. Currently I am able to use "sitename.com/user/login.html" but "sitename.com/user/login/index.php" is also loading! I dont want that, only the .html version should load pages.

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question by editing it** - also, explain what **exactly** should happen if anybody requests that "hidden" URL - should this request be forwarded to the public URL, should it show an error message?

Comment: @Nico Haase, updated question. I dont know how to explain it more clearly. but in short only the fake path should show in the browser, always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following rules to convert your `php` URLs into `html` :

```
RewriteEngine on

#Redirect and rewrite php URLs to html
#redirect /user/foobar/index.php to /user/foobar.html
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/index\.php$ /user/$1.html [L,R]
#rewrite /user/foobar.html to /user/foobar/index.php
RewriteRule ^user/([^.]+)\.html$ /user/$1/index.php [L]
```

The rule #1) triggers when `/user/foobar/index.php` is requested and redirects it to `/user/foobar.html` . Since the `.html` file doesn't exist the second rule maps the `.html` request back to original `.php` page but your URL remains the same in browser address bar.

Comment: @SamuelLiew  May I please know why all the comments posted on this answer were removed?

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before validating your URLs. As per OP's comment edited rules, as per `.php` and `.html` formats. I believe you should avoid giving both kind of urls to users and ask them to hit only .html urls in case anyone hits `.php` url you could forbid it(in case they are directly hitting it, another reason could be because if they are hitting `.php` directly then you want it to change URL on browser to .html which is actually being served by a `.php` file itself in backend), if they hit .html then that could be served by respective index.php of passed uri IMHO. NOTE: This is IMHO only and should not be used if someone has more requirements on this one.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/user/([\w-]+)\.html/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user/%1/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index\.php/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226247/discussion-on-answer-by-ravindersingh13-redirect-all-php-requests-to-html-usin).